# What does it mean when I install Jinja2 that "the speedup extension could not be compiled, Jinja will fall back to the native python classes"?

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm getting this message when I install it, and I'm not sure what the implications are. Can't find any information anywhere, and this is the first time I use Jinja, so not sure what to expect. Any information greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This notice comes from [`markupsafe`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/markupsafe) which has a [component (written in C)](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/markupsafe/blob/master/markupsafe/_speedups.c) that can be compiled to speed up parsing.

This component is only built if the appropriate Python headers are available; if they are not, Python parsing is used (which is slower).

That's what the warning is telling you.  Your application will still continue to function properly.